# Breaking letters but not words while wrapping

Tags: html, css

I don't want white spaces when the line is wrapped so i use `white-space:no-wrap;` but i want the text to wrap and not exceed the `div`

I don't want the word to be wrapped to the next line and leave a whitespace

Like look at the attached photo, i want the word **"Knights"** to stay on first line and the letters that don't fit then get pushed to the next line. How do I do this?[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? The word doesn't fit on that line.

Comment: Justify? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287150/css-making-text-align-left-and-justify-at-same-time Or [html - How can I allow text to wrap inside a word if necessary? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257657/how-can-i-allow-text-to-wrap-inside-a-word-if-necessary) ?

Comment: I got the solution...what i wanted was to only cut off the letters that didn't fit but not shifting the whole word to another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
white-space:normal;
word-break:break-all;
```

This is what i wanted to do:
[image]